# CSS - flexible div height

Tags: html, css

I am trying to fit the content within the div, by setting the height of the wrapping div `questioncard` to `min-height`. The problem I have is that if the element inside the wrapping div doesn't fit, it is not visible completely. This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="container question-wrapper">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 question">
      <div class="ratingnumber">1 av 6</div>
          <div class="questioncard">
            <div class="rating-question active" style="left:0;">
              <p><?php echo $q12textA; ?></p>
              <ul>
                <li class="a_Btn singleNumberButton" data-answr="Del4_1" data-value="1">1</li>
                <li class="a_Btn singleNumberButton" data-answr="Del4_1" data-value="2">2</li>
                <li class="a_Btn singleNumberButton" data-answr="Del4_1" data-value="3">3</li>
                <li class="a_Btn singleNumberButton" data-answr="Del4_1" data-value="4">4</li>
                <li class="a_Btn singleNumberButton" data-answr="Del4_1" data-value="5">5</li>
                <li class="a_Btn singleNumberButton" data-answr="Del4_1" data-value="6">6</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="rating-question">
              <p><?php echo $q13textA; ?></p>
              <ul>
                <li class="a_Btn singleNumberButton" data-answr="Del4_2" data-value="1">1</li>
                <li class="a_Btn singleNumberButton" data-answr="Del4_2" data-value="2">2</li>
                <li class="a_Btn singleNumberButton" data-answr="Del4_2" data-value="3">3</li>
                <li class="a_Btn singleNumberButton" data-answr="Del4_2" data-value="4">4</li>
                <li class="a_Btn singleNumberButton" data-answr="Del4_2" data-value="5">5</li>
                <li class="a_Btn singleNumberButton" data-answr="Del4_2" data-value="6">6</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am showing rating questions as slides, so that only one is visible at a time. The problem can be seen on the image below, where when I have numbers that doesn't fit the wrapping element, they are not seen.

[image]

This is because I have the `overflow:hidden` set for `question` element. But if I remove that then the number goes out of the element, and the element is not expended. This is the css code:

```
.question-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        max-width: 500px;

        .question {
            background-color: $theme-pink;
            color: $white;
            margin: 0 auto;
            overflow: hidden;
            padding: 0;

            .ratingnumber {
                background: #C06;
                height: 45px;
                line-height: 2.4em;
                font-weight: 700;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .questioncard {
                position: relative;
                padding: 20px 0;
                height: 280px;

                .rating-question {
                    position: absolute;
                    left: 100%;
                    width: 100%;

                    p {
                        font-size: 1.3em;
                        line-height: 1.2em;
                        padding: 0 25px;
                        min-height: 190px;
                        text-align: center;
                    }

                    ul {
                        list-style: none;
                        padding: 0;
                        margin: 0 20px;
                        text-align: center;

                        li {
                            display: inline-block;
                            background: #712584;
                            width: 40px;
                            height: 40px;
                            box-sizing: border-box;
                            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                            border-radius: 20px;
                            margin: 0 8px;
                            font-size: 1.6em;
                            line-height: 1.45em;
                            text-align: center;
                            position: relative;
                            box-shadow: 6px 3px 0px #B9005D;
                            cursor: pointer;

                            &.selected {
                                background-color: #cad101;
                                border: 3px solid #FFF;
                                color: #000;
                                line-height: 1.25em;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        &:after {
            content: '';
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            position: relative;
            bottom: 0px;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            margin: 0 auto;
            border-top: 20px solid #de0067;
            border-right: 20px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
            border-left: 20px solid transparent;
        }
    }

    .next-button {
        .nextratingbtn {
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 1.5em;
            position: relative;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
            max-width: 400px;
            margin: 20px auto;
            display: none;

            &:hover {
                color: #FFF;
            }

            &:before {
                background-image: url(../images/icons/arrowright.png);
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                content: "";
                height: 40px;
                left: calc(50% - 14px);
                position: absolute;
                top: -36px;
                transform: rotate(90deg);
                width: 30px;
            }
        }
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 414px) {
    .mainholder.part4 {
        .question-wrapper {
            .question {
                ul li {
                    margin: 0 7.5px;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 398px) {
    .mainholder.part4 {
        .question-wrapper {
            .question {
                .questioncard {
                    .rating-question {
                        ul {
                            margin: 0 15px;

                            li {
                                margin: 0 8px;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
    .mainholder.part4 {
        margin-top: 0;
        padding-top: 0;

        .question-wrapper {
            ul {
                li {
                    margin: 0 6px !important;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    .mainholder.part4 {
        margin-top: 0;
        padding-top: 0;

        .question-wrapper {
            ul {
                margin: 3px !important;

                li {
                    margin: 0 4px !important;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What libraries are you using? Bootstrap I could grok, but what else? I put your code in [a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/kss4sv2r/), but it doesn't really look like your screenshot.

Comment: You have set a height on the `.questioncard` element, removing that should solve your problem. It's difficult without know exactly what you are looking to do though.